# Verifying that a Regular Expression Matches

Tags: java, matcher

I have a regex that, according to what I can tell and to what [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/) says, does not match the full string I am testing (only its rightmost part). However, `matcher.matches()` returns true!

So, what is the most reliable way to determine whether a java.util.regex Matcher actually fully matches a string?

Also, suppose that one wants to use matcher.find() as follows:

```
if (a match was found)
{
    while (matcher.find())
    {
        // Do whatever
    }
]
```

Is there any way of implementing the "a match was found" condition check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

matches() returning true would mean there some match. Whether it's the "full" string or not, simply depends on what your regex is.
E.g.

```
"a"
```

would match all of the following

```
"a"
"abb"
"bab"
"bba"
```

if you're looking to match full string, your regex must begin with `^` and end with `$`
E.g.

```
"^a$"
```

would match `"a"`, but none of the following

```
"abb"
"bab"
"bba"
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `find`, use `matches`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've never had `matches()` not work, but you can use `find()`, then use

```
 matcher.start()==0&&matcher.end()==string.length()
```

I don't think you need the if, because the `while(matcher.find())` should check , but if you do...

```
if(matcher.find()){
    do{
        //whatever
    } while(matcher.find());
}
```