# Java repetitive pattern matching (3)

Tags: java, regex, matching, repeat

I am trying to solve a simple Java regex matching problem but still getting conflicting results (following up on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698499/java-repetitive-pattern-matching-2) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707417/verifying-that-a-regular-expression-matches) question).

More specifically, I am trying to match a **repetitive text input**, consisting of groups that are delimited by '|' (vertical bar) that may be directly preceded by underscore ('_'), especially if the groups are not empty (i.e., if no two consecutive | delimiters appear in the input).

An example such input is:

```
Text group 1_|Text group 2_|||Text group 5_|||Text group 8
```

In addition, I need a way to **verify that a match has occurred**, in order to avoid applying the processing related to that input to other, totally different inputs that my application also processes, using different regular expressions.

**To confirm that a regex works, I am using [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/).**

After several tests, the closest to what I want are the following two Regular Expressions, suggested in the questions I quoted above:

```
1. (?:\||^)([^\\|]*) 
2. \G([^\|]+?)_?\||\G()\||\G([^\|]*)$
```

Using either of these, if I run a **matcher.find()** loop I get:

- All the text groups, with the underscore included in the end, from Regex 1
- All the text groups apart from the last, with no underscore but 2 empty groups in the end, from Regex 2.

So, apparently Regex 2 is not correct (and RegexPal also does not show it as matching).

I could use **Regex 1** and do some post-processing to remove the trailing underscore, although ideally I would like the regex to do that for me.

However, none of the two aforementioned regular expressions returns true for **matcher.matches()**, whereas **matcher.find()** is always true even for totally irrelevant input (reasonable, since there will often be at least 1 matching group, even in other text).

I thus have two **questions**:

1. Is there a correct (fully working) **regex that excludes the trailing underscore**?
2. Is there any way of checking that **only the correct regex has matched**?

The code used to test Regex 1, is something like

```
String input = "Text group 1_|Text group 2_|||Text group 5_|||Text group 8";

Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?:\\||^)([^\\\\|]*)").matcher(input);

if (matcher.matches())
{
    System.out.println("Input MATCHED: " + input);

    while (matcher.find())
    {
        System.out.println("\t\t" + matcher.group(1));
    }

}
else
{
    System.out.println("\tInput NOT MATCHED: " + input);
}
```

Using the above code always results in "NOT MATCHED". Removing the if/else and only using **matcher.find() does retrieve all text groups**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Matcher#matches` method attempts to match the entire input sequence against the pattern, that is why you are getting the result `Input NOT MATCHED`. See the documentation here http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches

If you want to exclude the trailing underscore you can use this regex (slight modification of what you already have)

```
(?:\\||^)([^\\\\|_]*)
```

This would work if you are sure that `_` comes just before `|`.

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks. I know about matcher, but still need to figure out how the regular expression ONLY matches the correct input and not anything else. Is there any way of verifying that?

Comment: @PNS If you want to go for a tool, RegexBuddy(not free) is the best out there. And if you want to verify using code, then what you are doing is already right i.e. looping through the matches and printing them out and verifying them manually on several test cases.

Answer (score 1):

RegexPal is a JavaScript regex tool.  The Java and JavaScript regular expression languages differ. Consider using a Java Regex tool; perhaps [this one](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/RegexTester/regex-tester.html)

This may be close to what you want: `(?:([^_\|]+)_{0,1}+\|*)+`

***Edit:*** Code added.
In java 6 this prints each group (the find() loop).

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String input = "Text group 1_|Text group 2_|||Text group 5_|||Text group 8";
    Matcher matcher;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:([^_\\|]+)_{0,1}+\\|*)+");
    Pattern groupPattern = Pattern.compile("(?:([^_\\|]+)_{0,1}+\\|*)");

    matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    if (matcher.matches())
    {
        Matcher groupMatcher;

        System.out.println("matcher.matches() is true");
        int groupCount = matcher.groupCount();
        for (int index = 1; index <= groupCount; ++index)
        {
            System.out.print("group (pattern)[");
            System.out.print(index);
            System.out.print("]: ");
            System.out.println(matcher.group(index));
        }

        groupMatcher = groupPattern.matcher(input);
        while (groupMatcher.find())
        {
            System.out.print("group (groupPattern):");
            System.out.println(groupMatcher.group());
                            System.out.println(groupMatcher.group(1));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("No match");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. The regex doesn't work, unless the + sign is removed after {0,1} and, even then, it matches the entire string, so find() gives only 1 group and not the individual ones required.

Comment: I ended up doing some string comparisons in the file, without regular expressions, to get only the correct matches. Thanks again for all the help!